# Struts 1 form validation

Tags: struts-1

I'm using struts 1 in legacy project. I want to validate form. I have read good  [article](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-file-upload-example/) about that. But I don't understand what struts do if form's validate method returns non-empty ActionErrors. I have specified `validate="true"` and `input="somepage.jsp"` in action, but I get a blank page if my form's validation doesn't pass. As I understnad it has to stay at page specified in input? Am I right?

**edit**

```
 <action path="/struts/BlaBlaAction" 
                type="com.example.BlaBlaAction"
                name="BlaBlaForm"
                validate="true"
                scope="request"
                input="/struts/blablainput.jsp">
              <forward name="someaction" path="/struts/AnotherAction.do"/>
              <forward name="error" path="/error.html" redirect="true"/>
 </action>
```

Folder struts resides in the root of my app

Answer (score 2):

You also need to display the validation errors using `<html:errors/>` tag, in somepage.jsp

If your form's validate method returns non-empty ActionErrors, Struts would redirect to the JSP you have defined as input. And then if you have `<html:errors>` in the input JSP, all the ActionErrors are iterated and displayed.

Comment: If I don't display those errors with <html:errors/>, will I get a blank page?

Comment: Yes, <html:errors/> is the way to display the errors that validate() has thrown, if not, there is no way how struts would magically display them.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the action mapping entry in struts-config.xml & the folder structure for the project. All I could think of at this time is, the path mentioned in "input" isn't correctly resolving to the location where somepage.jsp resides.

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgot the **"failure" forward in your struts XML** configuration. Look at this example:

```
<action path="/LogonSubmit" type="app.jcj.LogonAction" name="logonForm" 
           scope="request" validate="true" input="/pages/Logon.jsp">
    <forward name="success" path="/pages/Welcome.jsp"/>
    <forward name="failure" path="/pages/Logon.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Comment: So I have to specify this "failure" in my action too?

Comment: yes, you may send to the same page as the success if you want, but you need to explicitly declare this. Try and tell us if this solution worked

Comment: @maks You don't need a "failure" result; in general you'd use the `getInputForward()` method to return to the page defined as the `input` for the action. You *may* have a different failure forward, but if it's the same page as your input, use what the framework gives you.

Comment: According to the link provided by me there is no need to forward to some page in case of failure in action class, is it a mistake in example?

Comment: @maks It's not a mistake, it's a design decision. The default Struts 1 `RequestProcessor` will automatically call the form's validate method and forward to the `"input"` attribute's page on errors. Whether or not using the automatic validation functionality is a good idea is debatable, but it depends on what you actually need. If you call `validate()` manually or have other ways of failing, you might call `getInputForward()` yourself. It all depends.

Comment: after a few experiments I've learned that it's true that struts calls form's validate method, but it doesn't forward to input element.